# Using jQuery mask and backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, maskedinput

Using backbone and requirejs.  I want to use an input mask.  I put another jQuery construct in the view and it works just fine, but the mask doesn't show up in the phone fields.  What am I doing wrong?    Thanks.

```
render: function(){
var compiledTemplate = _.template( RegisterTemplate, this.model );
this.$el.html(compiledTemplate); 

  $("#custphone").mask("(999) 999-9999");  //masks not showing up
  $("#custphone2").mask("(999) 999-9999");
  $("#custzip").mask("99999");
  $("#venuezip").mask("99999");

  $().acknowledgeinput({               //works fine!
          success_color: '#00FF00',
      danger_color: '#FF0000',
      update_on: 'keyup'
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual pattern for putting a view on the page looks like this:

```
var v = new SomeView();
$(something).append(v.render().el);
```

The `v.render()` call adds some HTML to the view's `el` but the `el` won't be on the page until after the `append` finishes and that happens after `render` has completed. So if you have a `render` like this:

```
this.$el.html('<span id="pancakes">Pancakes</span>');
var $pancakes = $('#pancakes');
```

then `$pancakes` will be empty as `#pancakes` is inside `this.$el` but it isn't on that page yet and `$('#pancakes')` will look on the page.

Back to your code, I'd guess that `#custphone` and friends come from your template. That means that they'll be in the view's `$el` but not the page itself when you `$('#custphone').mask(...)`; the result is that you're calling `mask` on a bunch of empty jQuery objects.

You can use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to look for those elements in the right place:

```
this.$el.find('#custphone').mask('(999) 999-9999');
//...
```

or you can use the [`this.$`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) function that Backbone sets up for you:

> **$ (jQuery)** `view.$(selector)`
>
> If jQuery is included on the page, each view has a **$** function that runs queries scoped within the view's element. [...] It's equivalent to running: `view.$el.find(selector)`.

So `this.$(x)` is more or less a short form of `this.$el.find(x)` and you'd say:

```
this.$('#custphone').mask('(999) 999-9999');
//...
```

Comment: Thanks - this "render problem" seems to come up a lot.  So View/render() takes my template and uses it to add nodes to the DOM, and in my View/render() I am setting up new DOM items, but if I refer to the current DOM, since my nodes are not present in the instantiated/current HTML, so it was kind of a null reference?

Comment: Almost. `render` (usually) only puts things into `this.el`, nothing gets into the DOM until someone puts your view's `el` on the page. If you say `this.$('#id')` then you're looking for `#id` inside `this.el`, if you say `$('#id')` then you're looking at the main DOM that is being displayed on the page; if `#id` isn't on the page yet then `$('#id').length` will be zero and you won't be able to do anything useful with it.